# Finite expectation of bank account with CIR interest rate model

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

The CIR interest rate model is 
$$dr_t=(\theta-ar_t)\,dt+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}\,dW_t\;.$$
The money account with this interest rate is 
$$e^{\int_0^tr_s\,ds}\;.$$
It is known that 
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{\int_0^tr_s\,ds}]$$
is fiinite. How to show this is finite.
That is, the expected value of account with CIR interest rate is finite.

Comment: @ intu : Hint :First note that $r_t$ has moments of all orders as is proved here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944181/martingality-theorem-solving-expectation-of-a-stochastic-integral/953779#953779