# Prove that the integral of the moments of Cox–Ingersoll–Ross model is finite

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to prove that the following integral is almost surely finite.

Assume $X$ is a stochastic process such that
$$ dX_t = \kappa (\theta - X_t)dt + \sigma\sqrt{X_t}dW_t . $$
I would like to prove that for $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ and $T>0$ we have that
$$ \int_0^T |X_t|^ndt < \infty \quad\mathbb{P}-a.s. $$
I do not know whether it is true or not! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look here to my answer to this post here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944181/martingality-theorem-solving-expectation-of-a-stochastic-integral/953779#953779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here [Does finite expectation imply bounded random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790106/does-finite-expectation-imply-bounded-random-variable), it suffices to show that

$$ \int_0^T E[|X_t|^n]dt < \infty. $$

We will simply use [Application of the Burkholder Davis Gundy inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280256/application-of-the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Let $X$ be a weak solution of
> $$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$$
> With $b$ and $\sigma$ continuous and satisfying the linear growth condition:
> $$|b(t,x)|+|\sigma(t,x)|\leq K(1+|x|)$$
> Then for any finite time $T$ and $p\geq 2$ there is a constant $C$ such that
> $$\mathbb{E}\sup_{t\leq T}|X_t|^p\leq Ce^{CT}(1+\mathbb{E}|X_0|^p)$$

This is the case here since $\sqrt{x}\leq |x|$ for all large enough $x$. So for $n\geq 2$, we bound

$$ \int_0^T E[|X_t|^n]dt \leq TCe^{CT}(1+\mathbb{E}|X_0|^n). $$

For $n=1$, we simply bound $E|X|\leq \sqrt{E|X|^{2}}$.